# Linq ContainsMany function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following:

```
 List<int> days = new List<int> {1, 3, 6};
```

I want to do the following:

```
 var result = context.Rosters
                 .Where(r => r.DaysOff.ContainsMany(days))
                 .ToList();
```

Basically, I want to check if all items in a list are available in a list navigation property, something like `ContainsMany()`. How can I do that?

Comment: what is the type of `DaysOff` ??

Comment: @Selman22 it is a list of `int`s as well

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) + `Any`:

```
.Where(r => !days.Except(r.DaysOff).Any())
```

which is efficient since it's using a set. `Any` breaks on the first missing element.

Comment: It's linq to entities, so *set* doesn't matter. It's going to be transformed into SQL anyway.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: yes, i've overlooked the L2E tag first, but `Except` is supported which is the main thing. The last sentence is relevant to Linq-To-Objects only but it might be useful for future visitors. That said i would also prefer Selman's approach in db driven LINQ providers for readability reasons.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `All` method:

```
var result = context.Rosters
             .Where(r =>  r.DaysOff.All(days.Contains))
             .ToList();`
```